# Get all parent nodes with RecursiveArrayIterator

Tags: php, optimization, spl

Essentially, I want to use the

```
$foo = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($haystack));
```

Methodology, but instead of returning a flat array for `foreach()`ing through, keep the structure but only return a single great-grand-child node and it's parent nodes. Is this possible in PHP?

---

I've been tasked with optimising some of my company's (horrific) codebase. I found a function that recurses through an array, searching for a key. I *can't* replace this with a simple `array_search()` or `array_key_exists()` because the custom function also returns the parent nodes of the matched (found) key, instead of just a `true` or `false`.

How can I use `RecursiveArrayIterator`, `RecursiveIteratorIterator` or failing that, other built-in functions (i.e. as little custom code as possible) to return a matching node with it's parent tree from a search array? I want to get the fastest function possible, as currently this function spends 8 seconds executing 14 thousand times, hence my requirement to use built-in functions.

My existing attempt (below) is incredibly slow.

```
function search_in_array($needle, $haystack) {
    $path = array();

    $it = new RecursiveArrayIterator($haystack);
    iterator_apply($it, 'traverse', array($it, $needle, &$path));

    return $path;
}

function traverse($it, $needle, &$path) {
    while($it->valid()) {
        $key = $it->key();
        $value = $it->current();

        if(strcasecmp($value['id'], $needle) === 0) {
            $path[] = $key;
            return;
        } else if($it->hasChildren()) {
            $sub = null;
            traverse($it->getChildren(), $needle, &$sub);
            if($sub) {
                $path[$key] = $sub;
            }
        }

        $it->next();
    }
}
```

Example output for `$needle = TVALL` would look like this:

```
Array (
    [HOMECINEMA] => Array (
        [children] => Array (
            [HC-VISION] => Array (
                [children] => Array (
                    [0] => TVALL
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

The search array looks something like this (sorry for the vast-ness). There are more than two top-level nodes, but I've truncated it for brevity:

```
Array(2) (
    [HOMECINEMA] => Array (
        [id] => HOMECINEMA
        [position] => 2
        [title] => TV & Home Cinema
        [children] => Array (
            [HC-VISION] => Array (
                [id] => HC-VISION
                [title] => LCD & Plasma
                [children] => Array (
                    [TVALL] => Array (
                        [id] => TVALL
                        [title] => All TVs
                    )
                    [LCD2] => Array (
                        [id] => LCD2
                        [title] => LCD/LED TVs
                    )
                    [PLASMA] => Array (
                        [id] => PLASMA
                        [title] => Plasma TVs
                    )
                    [3DTV] => Array (
                        [id] => 3DTV
                        [title] => 3D TV
                    )
                    [LED] => Array (
                        [id] => LED
                        [title] => SMART TVs
                    )
                    [PROJECTORS] => Array (
                        [id] => PROJECTORS
                        [title] => Projectors
                    )
                    [SYS-HOMECINEMATV] => Array (
                        [id] => SYS-HOMECINEMATV
                        [title] => TV Home Cinema Systems
                    )
                )
            )
            [HC-SEPARATES] => Array (
                [id] => HC-SEPARATES
                [title] => Home Cinema Separates
                [children] => Array (
                    [DVDRECORDERS] => Array (
                        [id] => DVDRECORDERS
                        [title] => DVD Recorders
                    )
                    [HDDVD] => Array (
                        [id] => HDDVD
                        [title] => Blu-ray
                    )
                    [AVRECEIVERS] => Array (
                        [id] => AVRECEIVERS
                        [title] => AV Receivers
                    )
                    [DVDPLAYERS] => Array (
                        [id] => DVDPLAYERS
                        [title] => DVD Players
                    )
                    [FREEVIEW] => Array (
                        [id] => FREEVIEW
                        [title] => Digital Set Top Boxes
                    )
                    [DVDPACKAGESYSTEMS-3] => Array (
                        [id] => DVDPACKAGESYSTEMS-3
                        [title] => 1 Box Home Cinema Systems
                    )
                    [HOMECINEMADEALS] => Array (
                        [id] => HOMECINEMADEALS
                        [title] => Home Cinema System Deals
                    )
                )
            )
            [SPEAKER2] => Array (
                [id] => SPEAKER2
                [title] => Speakers
                [children] => Array (
                    [SPEAKERPACKAGES] => Array (
                        [id] => SPEAKERPACKAGES
                        [title] => Speaker packages
                    )
                    [SOUNDBARS] => Array (
                        [id] => SOUNDBARS
                        [title] => Soundbars
                    )
                    [CENTRES] => Array (
                        [id] => CENTRES
                        [title] => Centres
                    )
                    [SUBWOOFERS] => Array (
                        [id] => SUBWOOFERS
                        [title] => Subwoofers
                    )
                    [FLOORSTANDING] => Array (
                        [id] => FLOORSTANDING
                        [title] => Floorstanders
                    )
                    [INSTALLATIONSPEAKERS] => Array (
                        [id] => INSTALLATIONSPEAKERS
                        [title] => Installation Speakers
                    )
                    [STAND-MOUNT] => Array (
                        [id] => STAND-MOUNT
                        [title] => Bookshelf Speakers
                    )
                )
            )
            [HC-ACCYS] => Array (
                [id] => HC-ACCYS
                [title] => Accessories
                [children] => Array (
                    [AVESSENTIALS] => Array (
                        [id] => AVESSENTIALS
                        [title] => AV Interconnects
                    )
                    [PLASMALCDSTANDSBRACKETS1] => Array (
                        [id] => PLASMALCDSTANDSBRACKETS1
                        [title] => TV Accessories
                    )
                    [RACKS] => Array (
                        [id] => RACKS
                        [title] => TV Racks
                    )
                    [HIFIRACKS] => Array (
                        [id] => HIFIRACKS
                        [title] => HiFi Racks
                    )
                    [PROJECTORACCYS] => Array (
                        [id] => PROJECTORACCYS
                        [title] => Projector Screens/Accessories
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
    [SPEAKERS] => Array (
        [id] => SPEAKERS
        [position] => 3
        [title] => Speakers
        [children] => Array (
            [SPK-HIFI] => Array (
                [id] => SPK-HIFI
                [title] => Hi-Fi
                [children] => Array (
                    [STAND-MOUNT] => Array (
                        [id] => STAND-MOUNT
                        [title] => Bookshelf Speakers
                    )
                    [FLOORSTANDING] => Array (
                        [id] => FLOORSTANDING
                        [title] => Floorstanders
                    )
                    [INSTALLATIONSPEAKERS] => Array (
                        [id] => INSTALLATIONSPEAKERS
                        [title] => Installation Speakers
                    )
                )
            )
            [SPK-HOMECINEMA] => Array (
                [id] => SPK-HOMECINEMA
                [title] => Home Cinema
                [children] => Array (
                    [SPEAKERPACKAGES] => Array (
                        [id] => SPEAKERPACKAGES
                        [title] => Speaker Packages
                    )
                    [SOUNDBARS] => Array (
                        [id] => SOUNDBARS
                        [title] => Soundbars
                    )
                    [CENTRES] => Array (
                        [id] => CENTRES
                        [title] => Centres
                    )
                    [SUBWOOFERS] => Array (
                        [id] => SUBWOOFERS
                        [title] => Subwoofers
                    )
                )
            )
            [SPK-ACCYS] => Array (
                [id] => SPK-ACCYS
                [title] => Accessories
                [children] => Array (
                    [SPEAKERESSENTIALS1] => Array (
                        [id] => SPEAKERESSENTIALS
                        [title] => Speaker Cables
                    )
                    [SPEAKERSTANDS] => Array (
                        [id] => SPEAKERSTANDS
                        [title] => Speaker Stands
                    )
                    [SPEAKERBRACKETS] => Array (
                        [id] => SPEAKERBRACKETS
                        [title] => Speaker Wall Brackets
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The example below will not necessarily be more performant (in time or memory requirements) but avoids manually recursing through the structure and shows an easier (IMHO) way to build your desired output array.

```
function search_in_array($needle, $haystack) {
    $path = array();

    $it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new ParentIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($haystack)),
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
    );

    foreach ($it as $key => $value) {
        if (array_key_exists('id', $value) && strcasecmp($value['id'], $needle) === 0) {
            $path = array($needle);
            for ($i = $it->getDepth() - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
                $path = array($it->getSubIterator($i)->key() => $path);
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    return $path;
}
```

**Reference**

- [RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php#recursiveiteratoriterator.constants.self-first) iteration mode - required to see non-"leaf" items
- [ParentIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.parentiterator.php) - easy way to filter out the "leaf" items
- [RecursiveIteratorIterator::getDepth()](http://php.net/manual/en/recursiveiteratoriterator.getdepth.php)
- [RecursiveIteratorIterator::getSubIterator()](http://php.net/manual/en/recursiveiteratoriterator.getsubiterator.php)

**Bonus**

You could also use the [RecursiveIteratorIterator::setMaxDepth()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/recursiveiteratoriterator.setmaxdepth.php) method to limit the recursion to `n` levels deep, if your array also goes much deeper.

Comment: Thank you _very_ much. This is actually 8x faster than the old implementation (~8sec down to 1sec). I can't upvote you enough.